# What is the standard approach for event handling in case of Visual Inheritance?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, visual-inheritance

We know that when a Form is visually inherited, all of its controls are locked in design time. This problem requires that we place event handlers in the base form. Now what should I do if I want to place base-control event handlers in the derived Form?

Since the controls are locked, approach of double clicking on the control to add an event-handler should not work.

What is the industry-standard approach for event handling  in case of Visual Inheritance?

Comment: @Hans Passant's solution is the most effective approach of solving the problem without introducing any other complexity. Thanks @Hans Passant. It was a great help, coz I was able to modify my existing applications within no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer honors the access modifiers on the base class members.  You must change the Modifiers property of the base form's control from Private to Protected.  Recompile.  Now the inherited form has access to the control, you'll have no trouble overriding properties and assigning an event handler from the designer.

Comment: changing access control might lead to changes in design, and that's more the some people would like to do.

Comment: Right-click the control and click Lock Controls.  They don't have to change the design if they don't like to, this ought to be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

You handle the event on the base Form and use it to call a virtual method. The derived Form overrides that method.

Comment: +1 for that. The base controls should be as isolated as possible, and all access should be through virtual methods / implkemented private methods for upward access.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to add an event in the user control (instead of a virtual method) and then fire it when the internal event is fired.