# C# Winforms visual inheritance problem with DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-inheritance

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994772/what-is-the-standard-approach-for-event-handling-in-case-of-visual-inheritance) I have created a `BaseForm`, then set all its `BaseForm.Designer.cs` `private` members to `protected`. Then has had a visually inherited/derived `Form`.

Now I am able to re-size or modify all the controls in the derived `Form` in design-time except the `DataGridView`. I am finding the `DataGridView` as locked in the derived `Form`, even though it is not locked in the `BaseForm`.

What can be the reason? What should I look/check for again?

I have a base form like this: [image]

And I have derived a form like this: [image]

Comment: This is where things get ugly.  DGV has a fancy custom designer, it doesn't work for inherited grids.  Lots of the .NET 2.0 controls have this problem, I'm not aware of a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that VS designer locks controls that came from base classes. Because you have same initialization code you would change properties of grid inside of base class, that affects all other derived forms.

If you want to change properties of your grid, I would recommend to have separate grid for child form, since it should behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known problem..

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/284335/designer-prevents-access-to-protected-datagridview-control-in-inherited-form

You can create a user control class and derive from DataGridView class

```
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class MyDataGridViewUserControl : DataGridView { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with some .NET controls.
There's a good writing here:

[DataGridView locked on a inherited UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207504/datagridview-locked-on-a-inherited-usercontrol/207549#207549)