# C# Winforms Forms Visual inheritance problem with DataGridView/ToolStrp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying to create inherited forms for my application however I read about a limitation of some C# components for this type of design.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238716/12297511

However, when I try to implement these solutions I find that I lose some properties of the component. Does anyone have any ideas of ways to solve this?

I'm using .NET 5 (Windows Forms Application).

Comment: Just put the DataGridView inside a [ControlParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) element, as a Panel; set the access modifiers of both to `Protected`.

Comment: If you want to have properties being displayed in the Properties window of the IDE you can explicitly create those and have them return the specific DataGridView property, e.g. `[Browsable(true), Category("Custom Settings")] public string DisplayMember { get { return dataGridView.DisplayMember; } set { dataGridView.DisplayMember = value; } }`